# if IE conditional comments not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, conditional-comments

It seems like a silly question, but I'm stumped.

I'm using an if IE conditional statement to fix some issues in IE6.

In the head, I have

```
<!--[if lt IE 7] > <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie6.js"></script> < ![endif]-->
```

And in the ie6.js file, I have a simple alert, which works when I take it out of the conditional comment. But in IE, the alert does not show. I am testing on IE 6.0.2900 on Windows XP in Parallels Desktop.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the browser information in javascript to make sure it is IE6?  Wonder if the VM is choosing a different version of installed IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it without spaces in the tags:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is Internet Explorer lower than 7
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That should not matter as I have conditionals in similar fashion to how he has it and they work correctly for me.

Edit: sorry i misread your answer, I thought you meant the new line for the conditional code not the spacing on "]>" and "<!".

Comment: Brilliant - that works. It was the spacing between "]" and ">" and the similar spacing on the closing tag.

Comment: Incredible that MSFT can create a work-around technology that is so fragile. Just awful. I also have seen it work with spaces, and was just stumped as to why my conditional comments were no longer executing.